# Toad joining three tables

Tags: sql

I am a scheduler at a big firm and I would like to have an overview of everything that happens in my warehouse. At this moment I am able to use sql to track what (which pallets) is in my warehouse and if something is underway to the warehouse. This uses the first query in this [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=129c4a2e63e2eb51ec0c8dc2c88daa19).

It uses the locations table to determine all the locations in my part of the warehouse and then joins the inventory table to it to give me a description of what is on those locations and if something is underway the l.expt_cpct. Now I would like to upgrade my output by also adding what is underway.

What I would like to achieve is stored in the desired table at the end of the link.

For this I have a third table tasks with can give me all the tasks currently in the firm. I want to use this database to also add which pallets are coming to the warehouse. And then use the inventory database again to convert the license number I get from the tasks table to a description.

At the moment I have this code, (the second query in the link) but I doesn't give the result I want. I only get the pallets that are coming to the warehouse on both descriptions.

What am I doing wrong and can someone direct me to the right kind of join to use?

Comment: Those are **tables** not "databases"

Comment: It will help if you give spme example values from those tables, what you are getting when you run your query on the example data, and what you would like to get instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the information. I am quite new to this, so thanks for expanding my lexicon!

Comment: @Wodin I will add it in a few minutes!

Comment: Pictures of code or data aren't usually helpful. Have a look at [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584). Check out this article for some useful [tips and tools to make your post better](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Comment: @EricBrandt I just wanna know which kind of join I need to use to add the inventory table twice to this. One time for the location table and one time for the tasks table. I thought that the more I explain, the better help I would get.

Comment: @Michthan, you're correct. More information is generally better. But in order to re-write and test a query, the volunteers here will want data to work with, and a picture of data can't be copied and pasted into a code editor. Some of the tools in the second link I put up will allow you to paste in the data you show and will generate `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that will make recreating your situation possible for us.

Comment: @Michthan More information is the right idea. The point is not to just remove the images, but rather make it easier for people to help you by providing information they can cut'n'paste into an editor etc. Also your images don't even include all of the columns mentioned in your query. If you provide the table definitions, the sample data in each table and then a textual version of what you're getting and what you want it will be much easier for someone to help you, and therefore you would be much more likely to get an answer. Prob want to join on locations again, but LEFT JOINs complicate this.

Comment: Perhaps use this as a starting point: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b05ddc1a296dc5fef4e6e399596f16df - update it with the realistic data and fix the table definitions. Click `run` to make sure there are no syntax errors etc. Then cut'n'paste the URL into your question.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful comments! I will get working on it today so you guys can help me even better!

Comment: @Wodin, tomorrow I will definitely try to do what you ask, but today was a busy day at the office.

Comment: @Wodin, I added it in dbfiddle, I hope someone can help me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've got so far but it is very hard to know what you wabt

```
SELECT l.location, l.std_cpct AS STD, i.descr, l.curr_cpct AS BEZET,
  l.exp_cpct AS H_Onderweg, i.descr, i.lic_no,  i.QOH,
  t.lic_no AS W_Onderweg, i2.descr AS DESCR2
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON l.location = t.dst_location
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_inv_lic AS i ON l.location = i.location
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_inv_lic AS i2 ON t.lic_no = i2.lic_no
WHERE l.work_zone  IN ('TIP06', 'WII68', 'WIR06', 'WFC2D')
  AND l.status = 'A';
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but if I try it, I still don't get what I want. I updated the desired table, so I hope you understand what I want now. If you need any further explanations, please ask.

Comment: It works! I changed your join task t... to LEFT join tasks t and now I got what I need. Thanks a thousand times!

Comment: @Michthan Good to hear, note that there is a typo in my answer on the second join with `v_inv_lic` where it says `i.lic_no` and not `i2.lic_no`.

Comment: I noticed that too when trying the code out :). If you add those modifications I will accept the answer.